# Selenium: sendKeys to prepending text works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

So for java/Selenium test, I'm trying to update a text field by prepending a text to the current text available already. It works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox. How can I make it work with Firefox? Thanks.

Current text: *"Message"*

Prepended text: *"Added "*

> Result in Chrome: *"Added Message"*
>
> Result in Firefox: *"ded dAMessage"*

In my code, I have this:

```
Action mouseOver = action.moveToElement(element, 0, 0).click().sendKeys(prependedText).build();
mouseOver.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with the Geckodriver with Firefox 53+ and Selenium 3 , can you check your Firefox version and Selenium version and geckodriver version. 
It should work with  Selenium 3.4.0 , geckodriver v0.16.1.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest that you perform it in a series of steps instead?

Get the existing text.
Clear the field.
Concatenate the strings.
Send the new text.